# A variant of Mean Value Theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I was having trouble with one of the problems in Pugh's analysis text and was wondering if I could get some pointers.

Let $X \subset \mathbb{R}^m$ be compact, and $f:X \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous. Show that given $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a constant $M \in \mathbb{R}$ such that for any $x,y \in X$, $|f(x) - f(y)| \leq M|x-y| + \epsilon$.

There's a similar(?) statement to this one: if $f$ is uniformly continuous and $X$ is bounded, then $f$ is bounded also. So I tried to use a similar idea to prove this, namely using compactness to partition $X$, but I couldn't figure out how to show anything for any pair $x,y$.

I'd appreciate some help with this problem. Thank you! (Also this is not a HW problem, I am doing practice problems for exam preparation.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $\varepsilon$ choose $\delta$ such that
$$\|x-y\| < \delta \Rightarrow \|f(x)-f(y)\|< \varepsilon.
$$

Then let
$$
M= \sup \left\{ \frac{ \|f(x)-f(y)\|}{\|x-y\|} : \|x-y\| \geq \delta\right\}
$$

Your inequality is now easy to prove by considering two cases depending on whether $\|x-y\|<\delta$ or not.